# Как установить PDO MSSQL Server драйвер на PHP 7 под Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, pdo, драйвер, php7

Я установил PHP 7 из репозитория Ondřej Surý, как мне установить PDO SQLSRV driver на Ubuntu 16.4?
P.S. Я знаю, что это извращение, но это не моя вина.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Драйвер для SQL Server в Ubuntu устанавливается так:

`sudo apt install php-sybase php7.0-sybase`

В строке подключения вместо pdo_sqlsrv надо указывать dblib.